# Cmake Setting to make Installation Path -- /usr/local/bin

Tags: linux, cmake

I am using **sudo apt-get install cmake**. But when i use which is CMAKE it gives output **/usr/bin/cmake** 
What i want as output is **usr/local/bin cmake .**
What to do for doing that.

Any help will be really appreciated on this

Thanks

Comment: Maybe create symlink at `/usr/local/bin/cmake` pointing to `/usr/bin/cmake`?

Answer (score 2):

You used an official package to install cmake. These packages do install to /usr. Self compiled/written software will go into /usr/local to prevent problems with your package management:

From [tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html)  Linux Filesystem Hierarchy

> These days, '/usr/local' is widely regarded as a good place in which
>   to keep self-compiled or third-party programs. The /usr/local
>   hierarchy is for use by the system administrator when installing
>   software locally. It needs to be safe from being overwritten when the
>   system software is updated. It may be used for programs and data that
>   are shareable amongst a group of hosts, but not found in /usr. Locally
>   installed software must be placed within /usr/local rather than /usr
>   unless it is being installed to replace or upgrade software in /usr.

Whats the problem with cmake binary located in /usr/bin?